# Prevent javascript function from executing before JSON is loaded

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

In my HTML I have several buttons. A button appends an object to a json file named game.json. This file contains an array with objects. After appending a new object to an array I would like to get the length of the array.

For example:

game.json contains an array with 3 objects. After clicking a button, another object is appended to the array (which now contains 4 objects). Then I would like to return the length of the array (4). However, it returns the length before the new object is appended. I understand this is because of Javascript being asynchronous.

I tried to prevent this using the following code:

```
let mydata;
function checkData() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'db/game.json',
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        mydata = json;
        }});
    console.log(mydata.length)
}
```

However, considering the example above, this still logs 3 instead of 4.

Is there any way to prevent the log (or even better, a return) from happening when the json is not yet fully loaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You don't append to but overwrite the array.

Comment: Sorry, you are right indeed. Do you have suggestions on how to solve my problem?

Comment: Yes, have a look at the duplicate question.

Comment: I seem to have figured it out using the duplicate question. However, now I have another problem: I can't seem to figure out how to return a variable from an ajax call.

Comment: Well if the problem really is that you are overwriting instead of appending, the problem is the equal sign. push() to your array or concat() them.